# Mongo Model.find with condition not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js

MongoDb: The condition in **find** method not working, fetching no records

I'm using mongoose in my application,

```
AppUser.find({'applicationId' : '58abf9bdc3aa0f1b0b2e3c85'}, function (err, obj) {
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   } else {
     console.log(obj);
   }
});
```

But using without condition in find, working fine: **AppUser.find({}, function (err, obj)...**

Below is my schema sample:

[image]

has also set a reference in applicationId field

Comment: Have you tried `AppUser.find({'applicationId': '58abf9bdc3aa0f1b0b2e3c85'})`, rather than `AppUser.find({'applicationId', '58abf9bdc3aa0f1b0b2e3c85'}` ?

Comment: ya that i will try, its is mistakenly placed in my question

Comment: ya AppUser is my collection object

Comment: i need to display all records which match the applicationid, then how i will use findone

Comment: I've posted an answer which works locally for me. Does that give you the result you're expecting?

Comment: I found the answer, its not related to code, in db as per schema the applicationId type is ObjectId, but for dummy data me entered it as a String.. thanks all for support

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `toArray` on it:

```
AppUser.find({'applicationId' : '58abf9bdc3aa0f1b0b2e3c85'}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
     if(err) {
           console.log(err);
     }
     else {
           console.log(docs)
     }
})
```

Comment: what is the purpose toArray in this ?

Comment: `collection.find()` returns an `error` and `cursor`. To convert the `cursor` to an array of document you can call `toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

> use where

```
AppUser.find().where({applicationId:'58abf9bdc3aa0f1b0b2e3c85'}).exec(function(err, obj){
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   } else {
     console.log(obj);
   } 
});
```